# Formattable - Export to PDF

Tags: r, formattable

I'd like to accompany my ggplot2-visualisations with nice looking tables. Or  in some cases just display the tables. My target audience is not fond  of just being presented a table. It needs some clear indicators of 'where to look' so to say. For that I've been using formattable (see pct_change... columns).

I can export the table below in an image format, but I've been unable to fully reproduce it as a pdf. When I export it as a html, then print from the browser, I lose the colour formatting (see pct_formatter-code at bottom). I've tried Edge, Firefox and Chrome. Turning on print with colour does not help. So in addition to being cumbersome (the table below is one of a group of 150) to print via the browser, it also doens't give me the desired result.

I've also found a workaround here on Stackoverflow where someone wrote an 'export_formattable' function. This does indeed export in pdf directly from R. However I lose again the colour and when I open it in Adobe Illustrator, I also lose the arrow icons, they become like [X]-boxes. So that doesn't work either.

I haven't really tried Rmarkdown to be honest, simply because I'm quite unskilled in using it. From what I tried, it's seems it's not made to simply output a table in the way, shape or size I want. I don't want create a (reproducible) rapport. I just need a 'nicely' formatted pdf-table (or .svg!!) that I will then manually combine with a visualisation in InDesign to make the desired document.

Thanks for reading, hope there's some way to help!

[image]

```
pct_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                           
                           style = x ~ style( 
                             
                             color = 
                               
                               ifelse(
                                 
                                 x > 0, "#39870c", 
                                 
                                 ifelse(
                                   
                                   x < 0, "#d52b1e", 
                                   
                                   "black")
                               )
                             
                           ), x ~ icontext(ifelse(x>0, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"), x)
                           
)
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2019", "2020", 
"2021"), class = "factor"), Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Totaal_permaand = c(2243L, 2007L, 2884L, 2206L, 
2701L, 2325L, 1452L, 1721L, 3152L, 3067L, 3097L, 2554L, 3303L, 
2948L, 3325L, 3173L, 3504L, 3209L, 5924L, 4637L, 5735L, 6206L, 
4252L, 3479L, 4312L, 3128L, 4529L, 4170L, 3814L, 5587L, 9281L, 
4615L, 4426L), abs_change.M = c(NA, -236L, 877L, -678L, 495L, 
-376L, -873L, 269L, 1431L, -85L, 30L, -543L, 749L, -355L, 377L, 
-152L, 331L, -295L, 2715L, -1287L, 1098L, 471L, -1954L, -773L, 
833L, -1184L, 1401L, -359L, -356L, 1773L, 3694L, -4666L, -189L
), pct_change.M = c(NA, -10.5, 43.7, -23.5, 22.4, -13.9, -37.5, 
18.5, 83.1, -2.7, 1, -17.5, 29.3, -10.7, 12.8, -4.6, 10.4, -8.4, 
84.6, -21.7, 23.7, 8.2, -31.5, -18.2, 23.9, -27.5, 44.8, -7.9, 
-8.5, 46.5, 66.1, -50.3, -4.1), abs_change.Y = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1060L, 941L, 441L, 967L, 
803L, 884L, 4472L, 2916L, 2583L, 3139L, 1155L, 925L, 1009L, 180L, 
1204L, 997L, 310L, 2378L, 3357L, -22L, -1309L), pct_change.Y = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.3, 46.9, 15.3, 
43.8, 29.7, 38, 308, 169.4, 81.9, 102.3, 37.3, 36.2, 30.5, 6.1, 
36.2, 31.4, 8.8, 74.1, 56.7, -0.5, -22.8), abs_change.Y2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2069L, 1121L, 1645L, 1964L, 1113L, 
3262L, 7829L, 2894L, 1274L), pct_change.Y2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 92.2, 55.9, 57, 89, 41.2, 140.3, 539.2, 168.2, 
40.4), CS = c(2243L, 4250L, 7134L, 9340L, 12041L, 14366L, 15818L, 
17539L, 20691L, 23758L, 26855L, 29409L, 3303L, 6251L, 9576L, 
12749L, 16253L, 19462L, 25386L, 30023L, 35758L, 41964L, 46216L, 
49695L, 4312L, 7440L, 11969L, 16139L, 19953L, 25540L, 34821L, 
39436L, 43862L), abs_change.SY = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1060L, 2001L, 2442L, 3409L, 4212L, 5096L, 
9568L, 12484L, 15067L, 18206L, 19361L, 20286L, 1009L, 1189L, 
2393L, 3390L, 3700L, 6078L, 9435L, 9413L, 8104L), pct_change.SY = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.3, 47.1, 34.2, 
36.5, 35, 35.5, 60.5, 71.2, 72.8, 76.6, 72.1, 69, 30.5, 19, 25, 
26.6, 22.8, 31.2, 37.2, 31.4, 22.7), abs_change.SY2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2069L, 3190L, 4835L, 6799L, 7912L, 11174L, 
19003L, 21897L, 23171L), pct_change.SY2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 92.2, 75.1, 67.8, 72.8, 65.7, 77.8, 120.1, 124.8, 
112)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open your exported PDF in Inkscape?  I have edited several PDF files in Inkscape and not lost anything from the original PDF.

Comment: The problem is that the colour is lost in the html to pdf 'conversion' (printing it from a broswer). After I open the PDF in Illustrator or regularly open the PDF, the colour has already been lost. Does the colour reappear for you in Inkscape? Cause that'd be interesting.

Comment: Have you tried creating the pdf version of your `formatttable` using `pdf("path\\file")` before the code and then `dev.off()` once it's created to generate your pdf?

Comment: Hadn't tried that no, but no luck. It exports a pdf but with no pages. Something to do that formattable uses the R Studio viewer or something, I read about it but can't remember the details. Thanks for your help anyway! If there won't be any solutions, I read about another workaround, namely creating a Shiny app and then export a webpage directly. It's a lot of extra work though, so I hope someone will have a better fix! Thanks again!